# Jquery not working in rails 3.2 app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to get a simple show/hide going.. Its working in js fiddle just not in my app..

In my views/user_steps/interests.html.erb

```
<label class="checkbox">
 <input id="user_holiday_ids_" name="user[holiday_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
 Valentine Day
</label>
<div style="display:none;">
    Whatever you have to capture here<input type="text" id="foo" />
</div>
</br>
<label class="checkbox">
 <input id="user_holiday_ids_" name="user[holiday_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
 Easter
</label>
<div style="display:none;">
    Whatever you have to capture here<input type="text" id="foo1" />
</div>
</br>
<label class="checkbox">
 <input id="user_holiday_ids_" name="user[holiday_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="4" />
 Mother Day
</label>
<div style="display:none;">
    Whatever you have to capture here<input type="text" id="foo2" />
</div>
</br>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input id="user_holiday_ids_" name="user[holiday_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="5" />
  Father's Day
</label>
<div style="display:none;">
    Whatever you have to capture here<input type="text" id="foo3" />
</div>
</br>
<label class="checkbox">
 <input id="user_holiday_ids_" name="user[holiday_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="6" />
 Halloween
</label>
<div style="display:none;">
    Whatever you have to capture here<input type="text" id="foo4" />
</div>
</br>
<label class="checkbox">
 <input id="user_holiday_ids_" name="user[holiday_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="7" />
 Thanksgiving
</label>
</br>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input id="user_holiday_ids_" name="user[holiday_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="8" />
  Christmas
</label>
```

In my assets/javascripts/user_steps.js:

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
   $(this).next("div").toggle();  
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the error console?

Comment: Lots of duplicate IDs are a problem.

Comment: hiya, sorry, came online <2 mins back> isn't this same question as this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561210/how-to-show-hide-in-rails-form-with-jquery/ ?

Comment: BTW, where's this working fiddle you claim to have?

Comment: @Marc http://jsfiddle.net/z862m/ lol :)) anyhoo I will try to reply in your previous question NKeating! have a nice one, **just for record** I am not down voting its someone else, cheers!

Comment: updated version, not dealing with erb code anymore.. anyways no errors in console and @Marc, even when i remove the bottom 7 checkboxes leaving just "valentine day", same result..

Answer (score 1):

Don't duplicate IDs for DOM elements.  ID should be unique on the page, and if it's not, javascript selectors can become unreliable.